# How can i delete duplicate letter, but adding some exception letter to it

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

im trying to do data cleaning from instagram using python.

i need to remove those duplicate letters, but on (a,g) only remove them until there are 2 duplicate letters (aa,gg)

so it looks like this

input : mengganti, maaf, ppuuutttiiiihhh, mmmmeeeeerrrraaaah, maaagggz

output desired : mengganti, maaf, putih, meraah, maaggz

what im currently doing with regex is like this:

`re.compile(r'(.)\1{1,}', re.IGNORECASE).sub(r'\1',kalimat)`

input : mengganti, maaf, ppuuutttiiiihhh, mmmmeeeeerrrraaaah, maaagggz

currrent output : menganti, maf, putih, merah,magz

NB: it doesnt have to use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first capture `a` and `g` and replace with 2 times group 1.

```
([ag])\1+
```

The pattern matches:

- `([ag])` Capture **group 1**, match either `a` or `g`
- `\1+` Repeat 1+ times the same char matched in group 1

Then replace all chars other than `a` `g` or a whitespace char, and replace with a single group 1 to remove the duplicates.

```
([^\sag])\1+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\sag]` Match a non whitespace char except for a or g
- `)` Close group 1
- `\1+` Repeat 1+ times the same char matched in group 1

For example

```
import re

s = "mengganti, maaf, ppuuutttiiiihhh, mmmmeeeeerrrraaaah, maaagggz"

print(re.sub(
        r"([^\sag])\1+",
        r"\1",
        re.sub(r"([ag])\1+", r"\1\1", s))
)
```

Output

```
mengganti, maaf, putih, meraah, maaggz
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/414Zr6).

---

Or using a single pattern with an alternation `|` combining the 2 patterns having 2 capture groups, and using re.sub with a lambda:

```
import re

pattern = r"([ag])\1+|([^\sag])\2+"
s = "mengganti, maaf, ppuuutttiiiihhh, mmmmeeeeerrrraaaah, maaagggz"
result = re.sub(
        pattern,
        lambda x: x.group(1) * 2 if x.group(1) else x.group(2),
        s
)

if result:
        print(result)
```

Output

```
mengganti, maaf, putih, meraah, maaggz
```

See another [Python demo](https://ideone.com/i8B8zm) or a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y39j3J/1)

Comment: sorry my bad, what i actually needs, making (a,g) into 2 duplicate like (aa,gg) else is just remove the duplicate. but what ur suggesting is kinda closer than what i do before

Comment: @AnggiaBagaskara But that is not in the question right? Can you update the question with the right examples and expectations?

Comment: ive updated it, sry for my mistake before

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to regex is `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_dups(seq, exclude):
    # gather the intermediate results here
    result = []
    # for each letter and consecutive group it leads...
    for letter, group in groupby(seq):
        # get the length of the group
        group_len = len(list(group))
        if letter not in exclude or group_len < 2:
            # e.g., either not "a" or "g", or appears once in a row
            result.append(letter)
        else:
            # "a" or "g"; repeat by 2
            result.append(letter * 2)

    # new string with join
    return "".join(result)
```

or equivalently in 1-line:

```
def remove_dups(seq, exclude):
    return "".join(letter
                   if letter not in exclude or len(list(gr)) < 2
                   else 2 * letter
                   for letter, gr in groupby(seq))
```

`groupby` gives back consecutive groups with the key being the letter. If the letter is not to be excluded, it is put there as is; if number of consecutive letters is less than 2, it is still put there as is. If we need to exclude it, we put it with the repetition amount 2.

Sample run:

```
>>> remove_dups("mengganti", exclude={"a", "g"})
"mengganti"

>>> remove_dups("maaf", exclude={"a", "g"})
"maaf"

>>> remove_dups("ppuuutttiiiihhh", exclude={"a", "g"})
"putih"

>>> remove_dups("mmmmeeeeerrrraaaah", exclude={"a", "g"})
"meraah"
```

Comment: thank you, ive tried both of ur answer and it works too.
only that overall of my project using regex so i kinda slide more to using the regex